# Individual comment URLs in WordPress for URI integration across the web

Tags: php, wordpress, uri

I have been developing a comment system (reverse engineering the WordPress one). In my case I want each comment to be intractable with social networks. This means that they need they're own URL. I built a page (`comment.php`) and stored the ID of the comment as a get parameter.

The problem is that the social networks remove the get parameter so that they can store their own data inside it.

I then built it into the URL using the page numbers system as the comment id and then str_replace to get the id of the comment we want. (i.e. `example.com/comment/135`). This worked but the social networks removed the page numbers section. They do not remove them if a letter were to sit after the numbers.

Thus I am looking for a way of having individual comment pages. I have a themed file already made and ready to go, but I just need a standard comment URL that works. Something like `example.com/comment/135-comment/` with it's own page that can then extract the ID from the URI. How can this be done?

Comment: you can use modrewrite, i mean just rewrite example.com/comment/135-comment to /comment?id=135-comment and then use explode to get 135 from the GET variable.

Comment: Do the social media sites strip out a hashtag as well?

Comment: @Ryan some do, some do not but the problem is that they then do not copy the data at the anchor point they copy over the meta information of the page so they are utterly worthless anyway. Problem solved in any case using a page orientated string replace function as in the example below, except we made it a legitimate core script

Answer (score 1):

You can use htaccess rule to rewrite example.com/comment/135-comment to example.com/comment/?id=135

But this will work only if you have the resp. comment template in the url example.com/comment/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^comment/([0-9]+)-comment/$ http://example.com/comment/?id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

A generic way is to use something like `example.com/123-post/135-comment/` with both post id and comment id.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-post/([0-9]+)-comment/$ http://example.com/?p=$1#comment-$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Should work with most themes.

Comment: @tamilsweet.. Unfortunately that does not fix it as it causes Facebook to receive the rewrite URI as well, which it then filters out just as before. We need instead an effective page for each of these comments